# How to add a searchable textfield at the middle of the screen in SwiftUI? ( not at the top )

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-searchable

I would like to make the textfield below "Add Party Members" to be searchable. Upon googling and reading through the documentation , learned that a .searchable modifier exists but the position of the textfield would be on the top .

Is there any way to customise the location of the searchable textfield in SwiftUI ?[image: The screen where im facing this problem]

I tried using the .searchable modifier on a list and a textfield in the middle of the screen . However , the results were pretty much the same .[image: The result creates a new white space without any text or list]

The code I used is given below :

```
struct AddExpenseView: View {
@State var expense : Expenses

@State var newExpenseItem = expenseItem()
@State private var searchQuery = ""
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack{
          Form{
                Section{
                    TextField("Name:",text: $newExpenseItem.name)
                    TextField("Amount:", value: $newExpenseItem.amount , format: .currency(code: "INR"))
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    TextField("Type:", text: $newExpenseItem.type)
                }
                Section{
                    Toggle("Add Party Members?", isOn: $newExpenseItem.addExpensesWithFriends)
                    if (newExpenseItem.addExpensesWithFriends){
                        List{
                            ForEach(searchResults , id : \.self){ result in
                                
                                Text(result.name)
                                
                            }
                        }
                        .searchable(text: $searchQuery)

                    }
                    
                }

           }

        .navigationTitle("New Expense")
        .toolbar{
            Button("Cancel"){
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
var searchResults: [expenseItem] {
       if searchQuery.isEmpty {
           return expense.items
       } else {
           return expense.items.filter{$0.name.contains(searchQuery)}
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: You have to create your own, searchable attaches to the NavigationStack